# Default insets are present in custom toolbar, despite change of the value in xml file

Tags: android

I created custom view based on Toolbar:

```
public class CommonToolbar extends Toolbar {
   public CommonToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.common_toolbar, this, true);
}
```

common_toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">         

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backIcon"
            style="@style/ToolbarNavigationButton"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_close" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/backIcon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

As you can see i set attribute *contentInsetStart* value to 0, but when i use this Toolbar in any layout file, padding is still present ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixMwK.png)). I can modify this by changing *contentInsetStart* value in destination layout file, but I prefer to keep this in source xml. Why is it happening?

Comment: Did you try setting android:contentInsetStart="0dp" as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your custom view extends Toolbar you are inflating your xml toolbar into a Toolbar. If you take a look at your layout with Layout Inspector, your view hierarchy will look like this:

```
<CommonToolbar> (Subclass of Toolbar)
  <Toolbar>
    <RelativeLayout>
     ...
```

So when you set contentInsetStart via xml, you are setting it on the inner toolbar. The outer toolbar still has a content inset.

To avoid this you can have Common Toolbar extend a ViewGroup i.e.

```
public class CommonToolbar extends RelativeLayout {
  public CommonToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.common_toolbar, this, true);
}
```

Or inflate the common toolbar using an include tag. i.e.

```
<include
  layout="@layout/common_toolbar"
  />
```

which allows you to remove the CommonToolbar custom view

Answer (score 0):

Use setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);

```
public class CustomToolbar extends Toolbar {

@BindView(R.id.txt_screen_title)
TextView txtScreenTitle;


public CustomToolbar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initToolbarLayout(context);
}

public CustomToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initToolbarLayout(context);
}

public CustomToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initToolbarLayout(context);
}

private void initToolbarLayout(Context context) {
    View toolbarView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.app_toolbar, null);
    this.addView(toolbarView);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, toolbarView);
    setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
}

public void setScreenTitle(String title) {
    if(txtScreenTitle != null) {
        txtScreenTitle.setText(title);
    }
}
```

}